# 3-D linear interpolation in SciPy with non-Delaunay triangulation

Tags: python, class, scipy, interpolation

In theory, linear interpolation can be done with any triangulation (not just a Delaunay triangulation).

I am trying to use `scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator` with a pre-computed 3D triangulation which is not of class `scipy.spatial.Delaunay`. However, this won't work because the SciPy code checks the class of the triangulation (`if isinstance(points, qhull.Delaunay)`...). I tried to create a 'fake' Delaunay triangulation with the correct class by changing the 'points' and 'simplices' attributes of a Delaunay object, but I received the error `AttributeError: can't set attribute`.

Is there a way around this, or another library for linear interpolation?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `matplotlib.tri.LinearTriInterpolator` might be a good alternative. I will update this post when I have tested this.

Edit: This is not a solution to my problem because it is only implemented in 2-D.